# Using selenium to scroll in a javascript window

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium to retrieve data that is a list of users. Unfortunately, the list doesn't fully load until you scroll down more to request the data from the server. I'm not sure how to scroll on this list. I know this command exists for scrolling the page:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

but, I don't know how to get it to interact with the scrollbar made by the javascript. (Think of something like Facebook chat).

Any ideas/suggestions would be very helpfu.

Comment: you may be able to call whatever function is fetching the rest of the data instead of explicitly scrolling down

Comment: any idea how I could figure out what that function is?

Comment: Use a debugging proxy such as [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to see the function being called on scroll.